# ReSharper break VS2010 automatic hightlight of usages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I recently bought my first ReSharper-license and I really love. I'm using ReSharper6 in VS2010 with the VS scheme applied.

However, what VS2010 did better without ReSharper was, that it automatically highlighted all usages of a variable or method when I put the cursor into them. ReSharper also has this functionality, but I must press Shift+Alt+F11 and I need to clear it pressing Esc. Is there a way to get the "old" VS2010 functionality back or to configure ReSharper to do the same (automatically hightlight usages)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure 'Highlight references to symbol under cursor' is ticked in VS settings (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced)

This was ticked for me by default, so I see this when selecting a variable:
[image]

Hope this helps.

[image]